# How to say in this situation?

Tags: word-usage

Here's the case.

Both A and B are value.

I want to describes A is smaller than B, and the difference (B minus A) is greater than 100.

How to describe that in one sentence?

A is smaller but above 100 than B?

It sounds really weird lol.

Comment: B exceeds A by over 100.

Comment: When [browsing for questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/), it helps if readers can tell at a glance what aspect of English you're seeking information about. Could I trouble you to please [edit] your title to reflect the gist of your question?

Comment: Hi Lawrence, could you suggest me the title to edit?

Comment: Even something simple and direct like «How do you say “B−A>100”?» would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that *A is less than B **by** at least 100*.

> **By** *preposition*
>   3 Indicating the amount or size of a margin:
>   ‘the raising of VAT by 2.5%’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by)

Comment: Excellent: not a single wasted word.

Comment: Fabulous!!!  It's what I've learned before, but I just can recall it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to say it among many others that exist would be like this:

> A is less than B while their difference is greater than 100.

or:

> A is less than B while the difference between A and B is greater than 100.

Comment: Good. Yet the sentence is still to long.